# Godot images scaling differently

Tags: godot, image-scaling

As I started developing a system to place down things such as workbenches for my game, the images of these items started to exceeded the usual 48x48. I centre them inside a panel node(64x64), that also acts as a inventory slot. I created a margin container and turned on the expand property of the texture rect node so these images always fill the panel. The weird part starts here, these images that are bigger than 48x48 are scaling slightly different for every slot I place them. Is there a way to stop this and make them at least look the same?
[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Use Gpu Pixel Snap". You will find it in Project Settings under Rendering -> 2D -> Snapping. It is off by default.

Comment: Thank you! The items finally look consistent